# displaying the different uploaded files as thumbnails or any other way

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have written code to upload the files of different types using php, and also i am saving their location information and date in database table.
i made a query to display list of files i have uploaded...and resulting output on a html page as follows

```
1.uploads/clouds.png
date and time

2.uploads/resume.pdf
dare and time

.......so on
```

is there any different any way to display them by their file types as like an operating systems do..... or any better way.... I am curious to know it... Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great script for generating file listings:
http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script

I also recommended you study the [php `glob` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). Can be used like this:

```
foreach(glob("directory/*.pdf") as $pdfdocument)   
    {  
    echo "<a href=\"$pdfdocument\">Link to $pdfdocument</a>"; 
    }
```

This will generate links to all PDF files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to categorize by file type then use [`finfo::file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

here is example how you can get mime type of files

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create arrays for your types
2. Create a single array of all the file names from the db query you have made
3. Loop through your filenames array (point no 2), matching a certain file type say png and place found results in pngs array (string match check on .png).
4. Loop through your filenames array (point no 2), matching a certain file type say jpg and place found results in the jpgs array (string match check on .jpg && .jpeg).
5. etc
6. Loop through your arrays foreach, placing them into a new and final array something like outputList array
7. Loop through your final array (which is ordered by filetype) the html. for each $item in $outputList echo etc.

There are ways in php to match on array, but not sure if you can decision process the output then so, simple is best.